# Got a blank page on React Vite with Typescript on a apache server

Tags: reactjs, apache, deployment, server, vite

I built my application using react, typescript, and tailwind and build with vite. I build the app and preview it with `live-server` command. and everything is fine

[image]

*note: can't provide more screenshot. it's on my live server

but however, after that I deploy my app, all the url are ok, but it shows blank page like this

[image]

if you notice, the app is loaded because my console.log shows so.

i dont have any idea why i got this problem

information about my page's directory on server

[image]

my .htaccess

[image]

please help me :((((